# FileList of file input in Shiny vs JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, shiny

The app below contains a file input and a button that console.logs the FileList object of the file input when clicked.

In the Shiny app, when I select a file, the helper text briefly changes to the name of the selected file before reverting to "No file chosen". Clicking the "Show selected file" button returns an empty FileList.

Here is the app:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$script(HTML("
  
  $('#get').click(function() {
      console.log($('#file')[0].files)
  })

});"))
    ),
    HTML('
<input id="file" name="file" type="file">
<button id ="get">Show selected file</button>')
  ), 
  server = function(input, output, session) {}
)
```

In the JSFiddle, when I select a file, the helper text changes to display the name of the chosen file. Clicking the button returns a FileList of length 1.

[Here is the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmerchant/a42m5v6n/10/)

**What's causing these differences in the behaviour of the file input?** In Shiny, I can use the onchange event to check if a file has been uploaded (using something like `$('#file').change(function() { $('#file')[0].files.length });`) but **how can I perform the check after the change event has taken place if the value of the file input isn't persistent?** Typing `$('#file')[0].files.length` into the console after selecting a file  returns `0` for the Shiny app and `1` for the JSFiddle.

I took a look at the Shiny input binding for the file input in `shiny.js`, there is a FileUploader function but can't find anything in there or the fileInputBinding that resets the value of a file input after selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x = null;
  $('#file').on('change', function(){
    x = $('#file')[0].files.length;
  });
  $('#get').click(function() {
    console.log(x);
  })
});
"

library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$script(HTML(js))
    ),
    HTML('
<input id="file" name="file" type="file">
<button id ="get">Show selected file</button>')
  ), 
  server = function(input, output, session) {}
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Stéphane, I did think of doing that but I'm wary of the use of global variables. I will accept your answer if no one else is able to suggest an alternative. Also, do you know what's causing the difference in the behaviour?

Comment: @user51462 Shiny resets the file input in order for a user to be able to upload another file. But I don't know where is the JS code which defines this behaviour.

Comment: I think the value is reset on line 5708 of shiny.js. It is to allow the user to upload the same file twice in a row. The problem is that I'm using a third-party plugin that needs to access the value of the file input in the DOM but it cannot do that if it is always `""`. One workaround I can think of requires me to modify a particular method of the plugin using `$.extend(plugin.prototype, [modified method])`. It works but it doesn't seem very safe to me so I wanted to get your opinion. Have you ever had to do something like this?